# SSL illegal state exception in jython

Tags: java, python, ssl, jython, json-rpc

I am getting the following error frequently but not always,

```
in __call__ return self.__sendself.__name args File "/Lib/cvplibrary/SSLCertificateWrapper.py" line 51 in wrapped res = f*args **kwargs File "/Lib/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py" line 240 in _request response = self._run_requestrequest File "/Lib/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py" line 254 in _run_request response = self.__transport.request File "/Lib/xmlrpclib.py" line 1264 in request return self.single_requesthost handler request_body verbose File "/Lib/xmlrpclib.py" line 1292 in single_request self.send_contenth request_body File "/Lib/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py" line 129 in send_content connection.endheaders File "/Lib/httplib.py" line 997 in endheaders self._send_outputmessage_body File "/Lib/httplib.py" line 850 in _send_output self.sendmsg File "/Lib/httplib.py" line 812 in send self.connect File "/Lib/httplib.py" line 1204 in connect self.sock = ssl.wrap_socketsock self.key_file self.cert_file File "/Lib/_socket.py" line 357 in handle_exception return method_or_function*args **kwargs File "/Lib/_socket.py" line 357 in handle_exception return method_or_function*args **kwargs File "/Lib/ssl.py" line 287 in wrap_socket return SSLSocket File "/Lib/ssl.py" line 116 in __init__ self.do_handshake File "/Lib/ssl.py" line 165 in do_handshake raise SSLErrorSSL_ERROR_SSL e.strerror _socket.SSLError: [Errno 1] Illegal state exception
```

Following is the code I am trying to execute by using **jython**,

```
import jsonrpclib
url = 'https://user:password@localhost/'
ss = jsonrpclib.Server( url )
version = ss.runCmds("ifconfig" )
print version
```

I am using jsonrpc lib with an added wrapper to the method " _request" as follows

```
@trust_all_certificates
def _request(self, methodname, params, rpcid=None):
    request = dumps(params, methodname, encoding=self.__encoding,
                    rpcid=rpcid, version=self.__version)
    response = self._run_request(request)
    check_for_errors(response)
    return response['result']
```

and the wrapper is taken from : http://tech.pedersen-live.com/2010/10/trusting-all-certificates-in-jython/ as follows,

```
def trust_all_certificates(f):
'''Decorator function that will make it so the context of the    decorated method
will run with our TrustManager that accepts all certificates'''
def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
    # Only do this if running under Jython
    if 'java' in sys.platform:
        from javax.net.ssl import SSLContext
        SSLContext.setDefault(TRUST_ALL_CONTEXT)
        try:
            res = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return res
        finally:
            SSLContext.setDefault(DEFAULT_CONTEXT)
    else:
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
return wrapped
```

how can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue, by increasing the waiting time in ssl.py line number 165 (Jython 3.7 library )

```
    time.sleep(0.005)  # Necessary apparently for the handler to get into a good state
    try:
        self._sock._handle_channel_future(handshake, "SSL handshake")
    except socket_error, e:
        raise SSLError(SSL_ERROR_SSL, e.strerror)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a race-condition in the underlying implementation of SSL, netty. The bug has been resolved in netty 4.0.34 and so, upgrading to Jython 2.7.1rc1 will solve the issue (2.7.1b3 still uses netty 4.0.33).

If upgrading Jython is not an option then there is a small work-around by editing `Lib/ssl.py`:

Add a new class:

```
class RaceFreeSslHandler(SslHandler):
    def channelActive(self, ctx):
        self.ctx = ctx
        SslHandler.channelActive(self)
```

And change`self.ssl_handler = SslHandler(self.engine)` to `self.ssl_handler = RaceFreeSslHandler(self.engine)`

Source: https://github.com/jythontools/jython/pull/29/files

Jython issue: http://bugs.jython.org/issue2401

Netty issue: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/4705